# Camera moves forward continuously in WebVR Cardboard/ three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, google-cardboard, webvr

I have been trying to get the camera to slowly, continuously move forward in the direction the user is viewing in a three.js/WebVR project, in an environment where only a cardboard viewer is required.

I have found out through a lot of trial and error that what would typically work in a non VR environment doesn't work in WebVR, I'm going to assume because the perspective camera behaviour is already being overwritten maybe?

So the following:

```
function render() {
    camera.translateZ(-0.02);
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Did not work, the camera remained static. So I thought about adding the camera to another object and moving that object:

```
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( cube );
cube.add(camera);
...
function render() {
    cube.translateZ(-0.02);
    cube.rotation.copy(camera.rotation);
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

The above *sort of* worked, the camera moved with the cube but the rotation was off. Looking through a cardboard viewer and facing north, it seemed that in order to have the camera travel in an easterly direction I would have to rotate the viewer 180 degrees east so that I was facing south.

I think I am getting confused with perhaps quaternion and euler rotation, or I'm missing a trick with vector3 positioning ?

Any ideas greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Make empty GameObject and make it parent off MainCamera, then attach this script on that empty game object.

```
GameObject cameraMain;
float speed = 2f;

void Start () {
    cameraMain = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera");
}

void Update () {
    transform.localPosition += transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(cameraMain.transform.localEulerAngles.x, cameraMain.transform.localEulerAngles.y, cameraMain.transform.localEulerAngles.z);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a dolly. This video explains why and how: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mpVG2Iitkqg

I've found a much simpler method, though. Let us say you have a camera and a scene:

```
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
```

Then build a dolly for the camera:

```
const train = new THREE.Object3D();
scene.add( train );
train.add( camera );
```

In the animation loop, first reset the position of the camera to the train position to be sure that the camera origin coincides with the train. Then move the camera in the facing direction, and make the train catch up.

```
renderer.setAnimationLoop( function () {
    if (renderer.xr.isPresenting) {
        camera.position.copy(train.position);
        camera.translateZ( - 0.005 ); // is used to move the camera forward (The camera looks down its local negative-z axis). Alas does not work in xr mode.
        train.position.copy(camera.position);
    }
}
```